# updating "placeholder" attribute using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, placeholder

I have a form with some fields getting some data using knockout.js (ver. 2.1.0).
For example, to update the "value" field of an input I put:

```
<input type="text"  name="contrasena" id="login-user" value="" placeholder="" data-bind="value: user">
```

I have a JSON to store the value a I want to use for "pass" keyword, and it works correctly.

I tried to set "placeholder" attribute using the same method, but it doesn't works:

```
<input type="text"  name="contrasena" id="login-user" placeholder="" data-bind="placeholder: user">
```

I tried to modify knockout.js file adding "ko.bindingHandlers['placeholder']" function based on "ko.bindingHandlers['value']" (modifying "placeholder" instead of "value" in "ko.jsonExpressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty" function), but it doesn't work correctly, it puts the information in "value" attribute instead of "placeholder".

Anyone knows the way to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to use `data-bind="placeholder: user"`, you can create a [custom-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) in your js code.

You were on the right path using `ko.bindingHandlers['placeholder']` but you don't need to edit the knockout.js file *-- in fact, that is bad practice*.

This would require a very basic custom-binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholder = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { attr: { placeholder: underlyingObservable } } );
    }
};
```

For a guide on custom-bindings, see [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html)

Although Knockout is itself inherently obtrusive, this is slightly less. It removes the knowledge of how the placeholder is applied to the element from the view.

In fact, if in the future you wanted to apply some sort of jQuery plugin to show placeholders in browsers which don't support the `placeholder` attribute, this would be the place (`init:`) to initialise the plugin -- you would also need an `update:` function in that case.

Comment: Use  data-bind="attr: {placeholder: ph}" instead.

Answer (score 112):

You should use the existing *attr* binding, like this:

```
<input data-bind="attr: {placeholder: ph}" />

var Model = function () {
    this.ph = ko.observable("Text..."); 
}
ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Comment: thanks, I created a codepen to test this out: http://codepen.io/logankd/pen/Gzorq

Comment: neat, no need for custom bindings, can be reused as-is

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with something that looks like this to set the placeholder attribute:

```
data-bind="attr:{ 'disabled': IDIsDisabled(), placeholder: IDIsDisabled() ? 
'textbox is disabled' : '' }"
```