# Knockout Component - Pass value across components

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

I am new to Knockout JS and learning how component works.

I have created two components to create employee and display list of created employees.

But I am facing couple of issues:

**Issue# 1:**  Click event of button is not firing up

**Issue# 2:** As soon as employee is created, I want to reflect all created employees in another component.

I have tried as shown in below sample

**Example :**  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwe802nc/)

**Source Code:**

```js
/********************* COMPONENT-1 ************************/

ko.components.register('emp-list', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
     var self = this;
      self.Name = ko.observable();
      self.Name(params.EmpName.firstName + ', ' + params.EmpName.lastName);
   
    },
    template: '<div class="name-container"><span data-bind="html: Name"></span></div>'
});

/********************* COMPONENT-2 ************************/

ko.components.register('emp-create', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
     var self = this;
      self.firstName = ko.observable(),
      self.lastName = ko.observable(),
      self.EmpList = ko.observableArray(),
        
      self.AddEmp = function()
      {
        alert('1');
        self.Emplist.push(self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName());

        for( i=0; i< self.Emplist(); i++)
        {
          alert(self.Emplist()[i]);
        }
      }
   
    },
    template: '<div class="create"><input type="text" placeholder="First name" data-bind="text: firstName" /><input type="text" data-bind="text:lastName" placeholder="Last name" /><input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: $root.AddEmp" /></div>'
});

/******************** VIEW MODEL ************************/

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
    self.Emps = [{'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-A', lastName: 'Last Name-A'}},
                 {'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-B', lastName: 'Last Name-B'}}];
             
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.name-container{
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.name-container span {
  margin: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.action {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.create {
  background-color: #cacaca;
  padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind='component: {name: "emp-create"}'>
</div>

<div data-bind='foreach: Emps'>
  <div data-bind='component: {
       name: "emp-list",
       params: {EmpName: Details}
  }'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel `self.Emps` is an array, it should be an observable array in order to refresh de UI when new Employees are added ( partially solves **Issue# 2**):

```
self.Emps = ko.observableArray(
  [{'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-A', 
                lastName: 'Last Name-A'}},
   {'Details': {firstName: 'First Name-B', 
                lastName: 'Last Name-B'}}]
);
```

Now, you need to pass `Emps` to the `emp-create` component in order to add new elements (also solves **Issue# 2**):

```
<div data-bind='component: {name: "emp-create",
       params: {EmpList: Emps}}'>
</div>
```

In the ViewModel of `emp-create`, change:

```
self.EmpList = ko.observableArray(),
```

to

```
self.EmpList = params.EmpList,
```

The `self.AddEmp` function has a typo.  It has `self.Emplist.push` and it should be `self.EmpList.push`  (EmpList).

The click binding in the `emp-create` component is wrong, it has `click: $root.AddEmp` and should be `click: AddEmp` (without `$root`).  It solves **Issue# 1**

The `self.AddEmp` function should add an Employee:

```
  self.AddEmp = function()
  {
    self.EmpList.push(
      {'Details': {firstName: self.firstName(), 
                   lastName: self.lastName()}}
    )
  }
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwe802nc/1/)

**Update:**

Your `emp-create` template has a wrong binding in the `<input type="text">`.  You have `data-bind="text: firstName"` and it should be `data-bind="value: firstName"`, that is, you need to change `text` to `value` in order the observable gets updated from the `<input>`.  Here [Value Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) more information.

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwe802nc/2/).

Comment: That works partially. When I click on Add button, it adds `undefined` in Employee List component

Comment: @user2988458 This is another question.  You can find an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636695/updating-placeholder-attribute-using-knockout/12673879#12673879.

Comment: It is not related to placeholder. That is related to `#issue2`. When you click on Add button which now works fine. But employee name is not reflected in list. Instead it shows `undefined undefined`

Comment: I updated my answer, it was a very basic question about Knockout, you are using the wrong binding and observable don't get updated.  :-)

But think that you have a problem with the placeholder.  If you don't write nothing, an click the button Add button, `undefined undefined` is added to your list.

Comment: Well thanks. I am new to Knockout world. So learning things slowly. :)

Comment: @user2988458 Welcome to Knockout :-)